# Using floats, how can I get the purple <div> box to line up exactly below the yellow box and to the right of the blue box?

Tags: html, css, floating

Using floats, how can I get the purple  box to line up exactly below the yellow box and to the right of the blue box? If I use clear left on the purple box it will line up right below the blue box, so that is not a solution.  Can see the image on the link below.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Float Demo</title>

    <style>

        body {
          background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        li {
          display: inline-block;
        }

        #box {

          width: 200px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 1px;
          border-color: Black;
        }

        .red {
          background-color: red;
          float: left;
          height: 200px;
        }

        .green {
          background-color: green;
          float: left;
          height: 200px;
        }

        .blue {
          background-color: blue;  
          height: 400px;
          float: left;
          clear: left;
        }

        .yellow {
          background-color: yellow;
          float: left;
          height: 200px;
        }

        .purple {
          background-color: purple;
          float: left;
          height: 200px;
        }

        </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="box" class=red></div>
    <div id="box" class=green></div>
        <div id="box" class="blue"></div>
    <div id="box" class=yellow></div>
        <div id="box" class=purple></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

[Click this line to link to the file I'm having trouble with](http://www.xjse.com/dave/float-demo-with-css.html)

Comment: Here is one solution I came up with but my guess is that this is not the best solution.  I used relative positioning to move the purple div to where I wanted it.  But again, I don't think this is the best solution.  There must be a cleaner way of doing this.  Any thoughts are appreciated.                      .purple {
          background-color: purple;
          float: left;
          height: 200px;
          clear: left;
          position: relative;
          left: 202px;
          top: -202px;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the yellow and purple boxes in their own div. Also, use a class for the boxes instead of multiple ids - having multiple elements share the same id is bad form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .lv-1 { float: left; }

    .box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #red { background-color: red; }
    #green { background-color: green; }
    #blue {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 400px;
        clear: left;
    }
    #yellow { background-color: yellow; }
    #purple { background-color: purple; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='red' class='box lv-1'></div>
    <div id='green' class='box lv-1'></div>
    <div id='blue' class='box lv-1'></div>
    <div class='wrap lv-1'>
        <div id='yellow' class='box'></div>
        <div id='purple' class='box'></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jpqq99h9/

Comment: He is using class, dot is class, hash is id

Comment: @LordNeo His HTML has five different elements with the same id "box". Multiple elements should never share an id

Comment: sorry, i tought you were talking about the colors class

Comment: Hi jsfiddle.  Your solution seems to work well.  By creating the container for the yellow and purple boxes, when the purple box clears, it clears within the container (it's parent element) as opposed to clearing with the body as it's immediate parent element.  This puts the purple box right below the yellow box and to the right of the blue box.  Thanks so much for your input, I really appreciate it!

Comment: jsfiddle -- Question - why is it bad form to have multiple elements share the same id? If we want to have object-oriented programming, don't we want the object to be a box first and foremost, and then if it's a different color to add colors as classes like I did? That would seem to be the natural way to think about the box as an object.  I see how you did it -- by making the colors the separate div's and the box as the class -- which works but from an OOP perspective is less intuitive.  However, I've heard before that having multiple objects share the same div is bad form.  Just not clear why.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is like having two people with the same identification papers; it doesn't make sense, since ID's are supposed to distinguish an element from all other elements. It can lead to unexpected bugs, like only getting the first element when you try using JS's getElementById. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) even says explicitly that ID's should be unique. Your point about OOP is interesting, but I'll have you know that in Python (the only OOP language I'm comfortable in), objects are actually defined...

Comment: ...with the **class** keyword! The way I see it, we first define an object class "box" that has square dimensions and a border. Each box object then has its own ID, which is used to give it unique properties (color etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a margin that would overflow with the yellow box + blue box but not with the blue box only:

Like (1600x900 screen):

```
.purple {
    margin-right: 1000px;
}
```

For the sake of giving a useable answer, you could use calc to get the right margin for each screen:

```
margin-right: calc(100% - 404px); /* each box is 200px + 2px of border */
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put red, green, blue as inline-block elements inside a div, but absolute position the blue. Make sure the div has position relative. Yellow and purple also as inline-block elements inside a following div.

Comment: Also, I'd stay away from floats, not needed here.

Comment: Hi Jeff, welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for your answer. Please feel free to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). While it's great that you have explained to the OP how to do this, some code samples would make your answer even better. You can [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37515258/edit) at any time to add these in; I'd also recommend editing to add in your comment including some info on _why_ you wouldn't recommend floats. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd also be interested to know why floats wouldn't be recommended here.  They seem to work well for the task at hand.